# How can I link a JavaScript file within a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to make my site modular but still static so I'm using JavaScript to add my header and footer. However my header has a date function using JavaScript so therefore it won't load because you can't load a JavaScript file inside a JavaScript file. Does anyone know how this is possible or any decent work around solutions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="header.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
  <script src="footer.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <div class="welc">
    <img class="" src="image.png">
  </div>

  <br>

  <header-component>
  </header-component>
  <main>

    <br>
    <div style="" margin:auto;>
      test
    </div>

  </main>
  <br>
  <footer-component></footer-component>
</body>
<html>
```

This is the linked JavaScript file:

```
class Header extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `
    <h1>this is a header</h1>
    <p>pretty dope, right?!</p>
    <script src="scripts/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('header-component', Header);
```

Comment: What about `import` and `export`?

Comment: hmmm, im kinda dumb and dont rlly know js well so could explain that please

Comment: [You can start here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: im not tryna import bits of data but the actual script? the only remotely similar thing i was looking for was the script module bit at the end but im tryna run a javascript through the linked javascript file?

Comment: Importing modules **is** about importing scripts (JavaScript code, not data).

Comment: @Pointy Technically we can import raw data as JSON with import assertions.

Comment: Just move your `<script src="scripts/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` into the `<head>` element with the rest of your scripts.

Comment: i tried adding the date.js script to the header but it didnt work

Comment: What have you got working?

Comment: no, alas, not yet lol

Comment: This should work `connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = \`<h1>this is a header</h1>
    <p>pretty dope, right?!</p>\`;
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "./date.js";
    this.appendChild(script)
  }`

Comment: ok, that does work but im tryna put it into the header.js file because in my actual header i have a div with a list of href tags that are displayed inline so it wouldnt be in the place i wanted it to be, inside the header not outside
EDIT: sorry i mean it doesnt work to begin with